# Invalid drive specification - Xcopy with long path names - \\?\C:\Some\Really\Long\Path

Tags: xcopy

I'm unable to use the above mentioned convention.
The command that I'm using:

```
Xcopy \\?\c:\108 \\?\c:\108_2 /e /h /r /y
```

An error invalid drive specification is received.  What am I missing

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you are doing nothing wrong - it's rather these older utilities that
are not accepting the newer long-path syntax.

Here is a test where `xcopy` and `robocopy` didn't understand the syntax,
but `copy` worked fine:

[image]

Comment: Note: Long path names must be [enabled](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am using Xcopy to backup only those files that've changed since last backup.  I think this feature is not possible with Robocopy.  The command that I'm using is xcopy D:\108\*.*  I:\108 /d /e /f /h /i /j /r /w /y /z.  If same can be accomplished with Robocopy than I'd be overwhelmed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Robocopy suffers from the same problem, as you can see above. You need to use third-party sync products instead of these antiques of Microsoft. You may see [this random list](https://www.goodfirms.co/blog/the-top-11-free-and-open-source-file-sync-software) if some free applications suits your needs..